What's the optimal area a rectangle can have inside this parabola?
If a parabola is of the form $\frac{1}{8}$ ${(42x-15x^2)}$, what would be the optimised area a rectangle can have inside it if the bottom (width) of the rectangle is aligned on the X axis i.e the y isn't less than zero?
Edit: Thank you to everyone for your help!

Yeah, of course you mustn't maximize the width. You have to maximize the area, as you were asked.

Make a drawing of the thing, first.

Apologies for deleting my answer, I found an error but do not have time to correct it yet. Will repost once fixed.

you should show your own attempt toward this question @Gupert   -1

The rectangle with maximum area will clearly have its upper vertices lying on the parabola (as otherwise we can expand the rectangle to a bigger one).
This means, due to symmetry, that the rectangle's midpoint will have the same $x$ coordinate as the parabola's vertex, that is, $\dfrac{7}{5}$.
The area of the rectangle will then be, depending on the half-length $a$ of the base of the rectangle, $f(a)=2a\cdot \left(\dfrac{42(7/5+a)-15(7/5+a)^2}{8}\right)$.
Differentiating we get $$f'(a)=-\dfrac{3}{20}(75a^2-49)$$ and thus $f'(a)=0\iff a=\sqrt{\dfrac{49}{75}}=\dfrac{7}{5\sqrt{3}}$, and this obviously must be a maximum (as one can check with the second derivative).
Notice that the width in this case would be $\dfrac{14}{5\sqrt{3}}\approx 1.616$, which is really similar to the value you mentioned gave a 'large' area.
Thus, the rectangle with maximum area will have the segment $\left[\dfrac{7}{5}-\dfrac{7}{5\sqrt{3}},\dfrac{7}{5}+\dfrac{7}{5\sqrt{3}}\right]$ as its base (with its upper vertices lying on the parabola).

The parabola $y=\frac{42x-15x^2}8=-\frac{15}8x^2+\frac{21}4$ has its vertex at $x=-\frac{\frac{21}4}{-2\cdot\frac{15}8}=\frac75$.
We have $y=\frac{42x-15x^2}8= \frac38x(14-5x)$. The roots are $0$ and $\frac{14}5$.
Let the rectangle be constrained by $x=\frac75\pm s$, where $s\gt0$. Then its area is $$2s \times \frac38(\frac75+s)(14-5(\frac75+s))=$$
$$=\frac34s(\frac75+s)(7-5s)=$$
$$=\frac3{4\cdot5^2}\cdot5s(7+5s)(7-5s).$$
Denote $5s$ by $t$. Then we have to maximize $t(7+t)(7-t)=-t^3+49t$. Its derivative is $-3t^2+49$. So the maximum is at $t=\frac7{\sqrt 3}$. Note that $\frac7{5\sqrt 3}$ is less than $\frac{14}5-\frac75$, so this happens “inside” the parabola.
Then the area is
$$\frac3{4\cdot5^2}\cdot \frac7{\sqrt 3}(7+ \frac7{\sqrt 3})(7-\frac7{\sqrt 3})=$$
$$=\frac{7^3\sqrt 3}{4\cdot5^2}(1^2-(\frac1{\sqrt 3})^2)=$$
$$=\frac{7^3}{2\cdot5^2\sqrt 3}\approx 3.96.$$

The roots of the numerator are given by $3x(14 - 5x) \implies x = 0, \frac{14}{5}$ and so the line of symmetry is $x = \frac{7}{5}$. Now since the rectangle must be symmetrical across the line of symmetry, take the right half and multiply it by two to get the area of the entire rectangle:
$$A(x) = 2 \cdot \frac{3x(14 - 5x)}{8} \cdot \left(x - \frac{7}{5} \right) \tag{$\frac{7}{5} \le x \le \frac{14}{5}$}$$
$$= \frac{1}{4} (42x - 15x^2)(x - 7/5)$$
$$= \frac{1}{4} \left(-15x^3 + (42 + 15 \cdot 7/5)x^2 - (42 \cdot 7/5)x \right)$$
and hence $A'(x) = 0$ implies:
$$\frac{1}{4} \left(-45x^2 + 126x - 294/5 \right) = 0$$
Luckily for you, there is only one critical point in the domain, so from the problem setup you know this value of $x$ must give you the maximum area.

very nice answer .... +1

The given parabola is :$${42x-15x^2\over8} \implies{15x\left(\frac {14}5-x\right)\over8}$$
For simple calculations i will be shifting the parabola so that it has vertex at $x=0$
This gives parabola as $y=\frac{15}8\left[\left(\frac {14}{10}\right)^2-x^2\right]=\frac{15}8\left(\frac 75-x\right)\left(\frac 75+x\right)$
Now let one of the vertices of Rectangle be$(x,0)$ then other vertices will be $(-x,0);(x,y);(-x,y)$,where $x\in[-\frac{14}{10},\frac{14}{10}]$
And the Area of the rectangle will be $A=2xy$
This gives Area as a function of $x:A(x)=\frac{15x}8\left(\frac 75-x\right)\left(\frac 75+x\right)$
Now we need to calculate the maxima of $A(x)$ which can be calculated easily as $A(x)\vert_{max}=0.808$
